# SWISS Light fare - Buying additional *check* baggage

Tags: luggage, swiss

I am booking an intercontinental flight with SWISS. I selecte the Light fare that *doesn't* include checked in baggage. However, then there is an option to add checked in baggage (23kg), which I chose. However, when I got to the payment, I see

> A part of your chosen tariff only includes hand baggage. If you want
>   to check in baggage, please return to the flight selection and select
>   another tariff, or add a piece a baggage on the "Options" page. After
>   completing your booking, you can also add a bag on SWISS Choice.

But the information about the selected options is:

> 1 additional baggage item(s)

which costs $60.

Does it mean it is 23kg of hand luggage? That makes no sense. Do I get checked in luggage with these options or does the light fare not have it at all?

Comment: The basic Light fare does not include any checked baggage https://www.swiss.com/us/EN/prepare/baggage/checked-baggage If you book a Light fare, it seems you can pre-purchase a checked bag at a reduced rate https://www.swiss.com/il/en/book/conditions/baggage-conditions but $50 does not seem to be the correct fee for an intercontinental flight per the Price List

Comment: Right, it's $60 - but my question is, is it confirmed it's a checked bag? Why does the website tell me there is no checked in luggage, even though I have pre-purchased it?

Comment: One possible explanation: If you book a two-way journey, normally the fee for a checked bag will be for only one direction. For each directions, the checked baggage option must be selected separately.